# Which database is efficient to store primitives arrays, Mysql or Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I have a requirement to store primitive arrays like `long[]` for every node.
I have two ways to implement this. One is to join arrays to `String` like `1, 2, 3` and to store it in Mysql database and to split the string when reading. Another is to store arrays in Neo4j directly.

I wonder which is more efficient, and how Neo4j store arrays, and is there any other better way to store arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are pros and cons to both methods.
Storing the arrays as a string in a MySQL database has the advantage of being able to query the data more easily.
However, it takes more time to split the string when reading the data, and there is a risk of data corruption if the string is not formatted correctly.
Storing the arrays directly in Neo4j has the advantage of being faster to read, but it is more difficult to query the data.

> I wonder which is more efficient, and how Neo4j store arrays, and is
> there any other better way to store arrays:

And Neo4j stores arrays as a list of values.

There is no definitive answer to this question as it depends on the specific use case. However, some possible methods for storing arrays in Neo4j include using a relationship for each array element, serializing the array into a string, or using a third-party library.